Modifying morphisms to track inputs and outputs
Suppose I have a functor $F$ from the category ${\bf 3}=(1 \overset{j_1}\to 2 \overset{j_2}\to  3)$ to the Kleisli category $\text{Kl}(D)$ of the distribution monad $D$ (the target of $F$ can be thought of as a more general Markov category if preferred).
Given this, I can obtain the stochastic map $m$ equal to $$F(1)\overset{copy}\to F(1) \times F(1) \overset{id \times F(j_1)}\to F(1) \times F(2) \overset{id \times copy}\to F(1) \times F(2) \times F(2) \overset{id \times id \times F(j_2)}\to F(1) \times F(2) \times F(3).$$
My question is, is there an "elegant/categorical" way to obtain such a map, given $F.$ Basically I'm interested in finding a way to translate a sequence of stochastic maps to a single map $m$ which keeps track of inputs and outputs.
I'm also interested in the more general problem where ${\bf 3}$ is replaced with a monoidal category and $F$ is replaced with a more general monoidal functor. The problem reminds me of limits and writer monads, but I have not found a sufficiently abstract framework to think about it with. Any help would be welcome.

For any category $\mathcal C$ with small products, any small category $\mathcal J$, any functor $J: \mathcal J \to \mathcal C$ and any object $j : \mathcal J$, there is a morphism $J(j) \to \prod_{f : j \to j'}J(j')$ that generalizes your construction. The product is over all of the morphisms with domain $j$.
By the universal property of the product, a morphism $J(j) \to \prod_{f : j \to j'}J(j')$ is equivalent to a collection of morphisms $J(j) \to J(j')$ for each $f : j \to j'$. This is easy enough, since $J(f)$ is one such morphism.
We can apply this to your situation with $\mathcal J = \bf 3$, $j = 1$ and $J = F$. There are three morphisms in $\bf 3$ with domain $1$: $id_1$, $j_1$ and $j_2 \circ j_1$ and $F$ applied to each one gives your map from $F(1)$ to $F(n)$.

Replacing the product in $\mathcal C$ with a monoidal product is tricky for two reasons. First, we have to restrict to finite products, since there isn't a notion of an infinite monoidal product in a monoidal category. Second, we don't have the universal property of products to work with anymore, but have to use fragments of the structure like your $copy$ morphism.
Still, it's not too hard to construct an analogous product and morphism. If there are only a finite number of morphisms with domain $j$ in $\mathcal J$, we can construct
$J(j) \overset{copy}\to \bigotimes_{f : j \to j'} J(j) \overset{\bigotimes_{f : j \to j'} J(f)} \to \bigotimes_{f : j \to j'} J(j')$.
The first morphism is repeated applications of binary copy, while the second uses the functorality of $\otimes$. You'll notice that there isn't any specified order here, so really this is a separate morphism for each permutation of the morphisms out of $j$. If $\mathcal C$ is symmetric, these morphisms commute with the symmetry in the expected way (as long as $copy$ does too).
If $J$ is lax monoidal (and in particular there's a monoidal structure on $\mathcal J$), this can be continued to a morphism into $J(\bigotimes_{f : j \to j'} j')$. I'm not sure how useful this is to you, but you did mention that your $F$ will be monoidal.
In the case where $\mathcal C$ is cartesian monoidal and $copy$ is the diagonal map, this reproduces the first construction, since for the projection onto the $f$ component $\pi_f : (\prod_{f : j \to j'}J(j')) \to J(j')$,
$$
\begin{align}
\pi_f \circ (\prod_{f : j \to j'} J(f)) \circ copy & = J(f) \circ \pi_f \circ copy\\
& = J(f) \circ \mathrm{id}_{J(j)}\\
& = J(f).
\end{align}
$$
So the $f$ component of this morphism is $J(f)$, just like the morphism constructed above for products.
